# Why am I getting 'undefined' in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
var textArray = ['#text1', '#text2', '#text3', '#text4',
'#text5', '#text6', '#text7', '#text8']

$('#capture').click(function() {
    for (var i in textArray) {
      console.log($(i).offset());
    }
});
```

Not sure why I am getting undefined in console. I feel like I am missing something very simple.

Comment: [Don't use for-in loops to iterate on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/how-to-do-for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: simple debugging: `console.log(i);` Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `for…in` loop in JavaScript loops through an object’s keys, not its values. You can use `Array.prototype.forEach`, given support; `$.each` works as a fallback too, since you’re using jQuery.

```
var textArray = ['#text1', '#text2', '#text3', '#text4',
                 '#text5', '#text6', '#text7', '#text8'];

$('#capture').click(function() {
    textArray.forEach(function (x) {
        console.log($(x).offset());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to index off the array like this:

```
var textArray = ['#text1', '#text2', '#text3', '#text4',
'#text5', '#text6', '#text7', '#text8']

$('#capture').click(function() {
for (var i in textArray) {
  console.log($(textArray[i]).offset());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `i` is the index of the item in array, you need to use `textArray[i]` to access the current item(if you had logged the value of `i` it would show 0,1,2...7).

```
for (var i in textArray) {
  console.log($(textArray[i]).offset());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not loop over an array using `for..in`. That is meant to loop over an Object `{}`

Use below

```
$('#capture').click(function() {
    $.each(textArray, function(value) {
        console.log($(value).offset());
    })
});
```

You can use `Array#forEach`, but IE8 doesn’t support `forEach`, so I did it using jQuery’s `each`.